# Several values in one mysql to json array

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm building a REST API and I don't know how to echo several values from one column, I want to echo several values from one single column to a JSON array like the example below. The column will be used to store the usernames a users friends. How do I echo this as the example below and how do I store it in the mysql using PHP?

```
{
   "friends":[
       "tim",
       "jesper",
       "wexx"
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how to get the values from MySQL and convert them to JSON format

```
$conn = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error());


// get the info from the db 
$sql = "SELECT names FROM friends ORDER BY id";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $output[]=$row;
} 

print(json_encode($output));
```

Comment: I get the respone: `[
{
friends: "frej, jack"
}
]`

How can I make one array for each user?

Comment: That's weird, they should be in an array. Can you send me some screenshot how are the results ordered in your MySQL?

Comment: @ninjaproq http://cdn.imghack.se/images/f64e830bec7e143a52d1223655e4cc3d.png like so?

Comment: @TimLilleSkuttBillström, here is a demo of an API I've made before using the same script [link](http://tlipo.com/json/pagination.php) and a screenshot of my PhpMyAdmin: [link](http://cdn.imghack.se/images/9cad30fba16badfb15c8faabaa7da9d0.jpg). Can you see the diffrence?

Comment: No I cant haha, tell me? @ninjaprog

Comment: The difference is that in my PhpMyAdmin the results are separated one per row. In yours they are comma separated on one row ;)

Comment: Do I separate them with they ENTER key or is there a other way? @ninjaproq